# Mysql I want user to upload there Url on My database

Tags: php, mysql, database

This is my form:

```
<form action="add.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="url" name="url"><br>
   <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

Here is my add.php:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "addimage";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO addimage (url)
VALUES ('')";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "New txt added successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Now when I upload text, it shows

```
txt added successfully
```

BUT IN PHP MY ADMIN it shows no text in Url column.

I have created 2 columns in my data base `Id` and `Url`.

It shows id number(1,2,3....) but not inserted text in php my admin.

Now when I set the value in add.php as http:\
It shows http:\ in all the fields of Url

Comment: Where do you ever use posted data?

Comment: what type of MySQL column is the URL? Is it a Varchar and if so how long is it? And you do realise that the current query is empty?

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO addimage (url) VALUES ('')";
```

You insert an empty string into your database...

Please add $_POST['url'], and sanitize it.

Comment: where to put $_POST['url'] in value('')